# Regular expression to check for two characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to check if the 
value is 'H' or 'T' 
or else it can be 'H' 
orelse it can be 'T'
or both 'H' and 'T'

this all is stored in an array

I'm using this regular expression to check these two words.

```
$combo  = preg_match('[HT]',strtoupper($_REQUEST['combo']));
```

it gives me success if the value is HT . If i put just 'H' or 'T'...or recurring 'H' or 'T' it doesn't satisfy the code above.

hope this might help you understand...a simple coin toss game which has two possible out comes 'H'- heads and 'T'-tails.....User can play 9 rounds in all... $combo is storing this combination which contains H and T only...I'm checking a php call here from url that I got eg:- www.domain-name.com/submit_combo_predisc.php/?prefix=p&uid=username&txn=9574621083&combo=HH‌​H&k=29c3550e430723e5c61a66bd03ba4ff5....

here user has got three inputs right and he wins certain amount for getting three combination right.in the url if I enter 'HH4' instead of 'HHH' it still displays u got three combo right and the user is given certain amount for getting the three combinations right....which is actually wrong....because the value passed are 'HH4'...n not 'HHH'. 
User can actually misuse the url to win unlimited amount....

Comment: You could also skip the `strtoupper` by using the `/i` flag in the regex.

Answer (score 4):

```
$combo  = preg_match('/^(H|T|HT)$/',strtoupper($_REQUEST['combo']));
```

this matches H, T and HT.

if you want to match TH too,

```
$combo  = preg_match('/^[HT]{1,2}$/',strtoupper($_REQUEST['combo']));
```

is the better choice.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a quantifier for that. `{1,2}` would work:

```
 preg_match('/^[HT]{1,2}$/'
```

Note that your regex was also lacking delimiters. That's why it only ever matched `HT` - because the square brackets were interpreted as delimiters rather than as character group.

---

Seems what you actually want (but never said) was to count the number of `H`s and `T`s. Then the simpler approach would be:

```
 $combo = strlen(preg_replace('/[^HT]/i', "", $_REQUEST['combo']));
```

Comment: The counter recognizes as 1 even if its HHHHHHH or HTHTHTHT or TTTHHH it is not incremented it should count the number of combination like 'HHHHHHH' count should be 7..

Comment: preg_match does not return the string length. Don't use that assignment. Use the third $match parameter and strlen(), as you were told before.

Comment: I m using the strlen function later in the code'$count  = strlen($combo);

 if($count == 1){
  $combo = " combo";
 }
 else{
  $combo = " combos";
 }'

Comment: If I dont use this  $combo  = preg_match_all('/[HT]{1,9}/','H T',strtoupper($_REQUEST['combo']));  preg statement it returns me the count perfectly..

Comment: Elaborate your question so that I can understand it.

Comment: How can I use $match as you suggested in the parameter..?? and what is $match referring to ..?

Comment: See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php The third parameter is `$matches` there.

Answer (score 3):

the regex must be

```
'^[HT]{1,2}$'
```

This allows following values: 'H', 'T', 'HT', 'TH', 'HH' and 'TT' but nothing else!

Answer (score 3):

```
$combo  = preg_match('/[HhTt]/',$_REQUEST['combo']);
```